# CSS forcing footer to top of page

Tags: css, wordpress

http://www.crossfitpolaris.com/

I'm having an issue where the footer forces itself to the top of the page when the screen size goes below 980px.  It's happening on every page on my site.  This is prohibiting mobile users or those on smaller devices from scrolling down.

I manually changed some of the footer code to customize the footer, but when i reverted that code back to the original it didn't seem like the error was in the footer php code.  It seems like the only other solution would be a CSS issue, but I'm not able to correct the issue.  I've search and tried to implement what I've found, but nothing seems to work for me.

Comment: Not sure I see the issue here--everything works fine for me (OSX Chrome 44).  What browser/device are you running on?

Comment: I'm on Macbook Pro OSX Chrome 45, also Chrome for ios 8.

Comment: Did you try making screen width < 980 px?

Comment: You betcha (screencap): http://i.imgur.com/0rlfJx1.png

Comment: Footer is fixed BEHIND banner image.  Try scrolling down from there.  For me, I can't scroll down because the banner is forced to the top.

Comment: Are you able to scroll down @the_red_baron?  screencap that?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Developer tools I see that your media query sets your "content" DIV's position to be "fixed" when the max-width goes below 980px. This hides the rest of the content from the view. Removing the `position:fixed!important;` allowed me to view the rest of the content. Line <strike>888</strike>891 of your `style.css` file.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 980px)
#sidebar-footer, #content, #masthead {
  padding: 0 20px;
  /* position: fixed!important; */
}
```

Comment: thanks, when i turn off position: fixed!important; in the developer tools, i get the desired results.  When I look at my style.css file, though, I don't see that line of code there in my wordpress theme.  I see the result (in dev tools), but not the line of code to change in wordpress.

Comment: One work-around would be to use a different value other than "fixed", what is the correct value for position?

Comment: Just set it to `position: relative`

Comment: For the current theme that you are using in Wordpress, line 891 of your style.css file has that line. You should either comment it out, or make the position `position:relative;`.

Comment: I can't figure out how to eliminate this line of code.  When I go into my css editor in wordpress, I don't see that code in my style.css sheet.  (screencap) https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4Qs0Rk0I6l6VmFoVkl2TnBkNXM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: When YOU load the page now, is the style.css sheet correct on line 891?

Comment: Yes! The fixed position line is not there anymore. Must be cached on your browser. The page works fine on smaller screen now.